# phpmyadmin 403 Forbidden on Nginx server

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403, phpmyadmin

I've installed phpmyadmin from remi repo on my Nginx server on Centos 6.x and then I linked "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin" to "/var/www/phpmyadmin". Main website is located on "/var/www/example_domain". now I see 403 forbidden when I open "http://example_domain/phpmyadmin". 
I only add this to server block:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
         alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/;
    }
```

linking "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin" to "/var/www/example_domain/phpmyadmin" didn't work either.
Please help me to fix this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a working configuration for nginx and phpMyAdmin

- http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/phpMyAdmin.git/tree/phpMyAdmin.nginx

This is the file include in the Fedora RPM (which cannot be in the CentOS package because of missing nginx configuration)

Also see

- http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/php.git/tree/nginx-php.conf
- http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/php.git/tree/nginx-fpm.conf

A important work have be done in Fedora to have such webapp working "out-of-the-box" with apache + mod_php or apache + php-fpm or nginx + php-fpm, but this won't be available for centOS before ... CentOS 8